# How to send data using socket in nodejs

Tags: node.js, sockets

I want to send a data from html page to nodejs server.I want by pressing a button "desactivate my account" a prompt window apperas and when a user enter yes the username of connected user was sent to server to destroy the model from the database.
profile.ejs:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Username:</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">

          <input class="form-control"  id="username" name="username" value=<%= user.username %> type="text">
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
        <div class="emaillogin">

            <a  class="btn btn-default email-signin-button" role="button" onclick="desactive()"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw"></i> <span class="network-name" >Desactivate my account</span></a>
          </div>

      </div>

<script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>

function desactive(){


    var desactiv=prompt("Are you sure to desactive your account?");
    var maj=desactiv.toUpperCase();
    if(maj =="YES"){

        var socket=io.connect();
        var user1=$("#username").value;
        socket.emit("desactiv",user1);

    }
    else{

        alert("no");
    }

}


</script>
```

The problem with the function mentioned below I can't send the username of the user I got null in the server side.However the user.username was displayed on the html page.what's my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery object doesn't have `value` property - it's `$("#username").val();` method

```
var socket=io.connect();
var user1=$("#username").val();
// not
var user1=$("#username").value;
```